# Failed to retrieve data from a database, to complete a listview

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview, android-database

I'm using databases to complete a listview. But I've run into a problem that is not solved.
The problem arises when I create a variable lugar of the class Lugar.

Here is the class code Lugar:

```
public class Lugar {
    private String nombre;
    private String direccion;
    private GeoPuntoAlt posicion;
    private String foto;
    private int telefono;
    private String url;
    private String comentario;
    private long fecha;
    private float valoracion;
    private TipoLugar tipo;

    public Lugar(String nombre, String direccion, double longitud,
                 double latitud, double altura, TipoLugar tipo,  int telefono, String url, String comentario,
                 int valoracion) {
        fecha = System.currentTimeMillis();
        posicion = new GeoPuntoAlt(longitud, latitud, altura);
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.url = url;
        this.comentario = comentario;
        this.valoracion = valoracion;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        fecha = System.currentTimeMillis();
        posicion = new GeoPuntoAlt(longitud, latitud, altura);
        tipo = TipoLugar.OTROS;
    }


    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public GeoPunto getPosicion() {
        return posicion;
    }

    public void setPosicion(GeoPuntoAlt posicion) {
        this.posicion = posicion;
    }

    public String getFoto() {
        return foto;
    }

    public void setFoto(String foto) {
        this.foto = foto;
    }

    public int getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(int telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getComentario() {
        return comentario;
    }

    public void setComentario(String comentario) {
        this.comentario = comentario;
    }

    public long getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(long fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public float getValoracion() {
        return valoracion;
    }

    public void setValoracion(float valoracion) {
        this.valoracion = valoracion;
    }

    public TipoLugar getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(TipoLugar tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Lugar{" +
                "nombre='" + nombre + '\'' +
                ", direccion='" + direccion + '\'' +
                ", posicion=" + posicion +
                ", foto='" + foto + '\'' +
                ", telefono=" + telefono +
                ", url='" + url + '\'' +
                ", comentario='" + comentario + '\'' +
                ", fecha=" + fecha +
                ", valoracion=" + valoracion +
                ", tipo=" + tipo +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And this is the Class Lugar where the Element method is I put lugar = new Lugar();. This line is what gives me error and I do not understand why.

```
public class Lugares {

    private static LugaresBD lugaresBD;


    protected static List<Lugar> vectorLugares = ejemploLugares();

    public Lugares() {
        vectorLugares = ejemploLugares();
    }

    public static Lugar elemento(int id) {
        Lugar lugar = null;
        SQLiteDatabase bd = lugaresBD.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM lugares WHERE _id = " + id, null);
        if (cursor.moveToNext()){
            lugar = new Lugar();
            lugar.setNombre(cursor.getString(1));
            lugar.setDireccion(cursor.getString(2));
            lugar.setPosicion((GeoPuntoAlt) new GeoPunto(cursor.getDouble(3), cursor.getDouble(4)));
            lugar.setTipo(TipoLugar.values()[cursor.getInt(5)]);
            lugar.setFoto(cursor.getString(6));
            lugar.setTelefono(cursor.getInt(7));
            lugar.setUrl(cursor.getString(8));
            lugar.setComentario(cursor.getString(9));
            lugar.setFecha(cursor.getLong(10));
            lugar.setValoracion(cursor.getFloat(11));
        }
        cursor.close();
        bd.close();
        return lugar;
    }

    static void anyade(Lugar lugar){
        vectorLugares.add(lugar);
    }

    final static String TAG = "MisLugares";
    protected static GeoPunto posicionActual = new GeoPunto(0,0);

    static int nuevo(){
        Lugar lugar = new Lugar("1Escuela Politécnica Superior de Gandía",
                "C/ Paranimf, 1 46730 Gandia (SPAIN)", -0.166093, 38.995656, 1500,
                TipoLugar.EDUCACION,962849300, "http://www.epsg.upv.es",
                "Uno de los mejores lugares para formarse.", 3);
        vectorLugares.add(lugar);
        return vectorLugares.size()-1;
    }

    static void borrar(int id){
        vectorLugares.remove(id);
    }

    public static int size() {
        return vectorLugares.size();
    }

    public static ArrayList<Lugar> ejemploLugares() {
        ArrayList<Lugar> lugares = new ArrayList<Lugar>();
        lugares.add(new Lugar("Escuela Politécnica Superior de Gandía",
                "C/ Paranimf, 1 46730 Gandia (SPAIN)", -0.166093, 38.995656, 800,
                TipoLugar.EDUCACION,962849300, "http://www.epsg.upv.es",
                "Uno de los mejores lugares para formarse.", 3));

        lugares.add(new Lugar("Al de siempre",
                "P.Industrial Junto Molí Nou - 46722, Benifla (Valencia)",
                -0.190642, 38.925857, 150, TipoLugar.BAR, 636472405, "",
                "No te pierdas el arroz en calabaza.", 3));

        lugares.add(new Lugar("androidcurso.com",
                "ciberespacio", 0.0, 0.0, 2000, TipoLugar.EDUCACION,
                962849300, "http://androidcurso.com",
                "Amplia tus conocimientos sobre Android.", 5));

        lugares.add(new Lugar("Barranco del Infierno",
                "Vía Verde del río Serpis. Villalonga (Valencia)",
                -0.295058, 38.867180, 000, TipoLugar.NATURALEZA,

                0, "http://sosegaos.blogspot.com.es/2009/02/lorcha-villalonga-via-verde-del-rio.html",
                "Espectacular ruta para bici o andar", 4));

        lugares.add(new Lugar("La Vital",
                "Avda. de La Vital, 0 46701 Gandía (Valencia)",
                -0.1720092, 38.9705949, 400, TipoLugar.COMPRAS,
                962881070, "http://www.lavital.es/",
                "El típico centro comercial", 2));

        return lugares;

    }

    static List listaNombres(){
        ArrayList resultado = new ArrayList();
        for (Lugar lugar:vectorLugares){
            resultado.add(lugar.getNombre());
        }
        return resultado;
    }

    public static void indicializaBD(Context contexto){
        lugaresBD = new LugaresBD(contexto);
    }

    public static Cursor listado() {
        SQLiteDatabase bd = lugaresBD.getReadableDatabase();
        return bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM lugares", null);
    }
}
```

The sample error is as follows:

Lugar() in Lugar cannot be applied to:

Thank you very much for the help, I am learning a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have

```
public Lugar(String nombre, String direccion, double longitud,
             double latitud, double altura, TipoLugar tipo,  int telefono, String url, String comentario,
             int valoracion)
```

in your `Lugar` class, default constructor won't be available.

Either you need to always use above constructor or define an empty constructor

```
public Lugar() {
}
```

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827346/using-default-constructors-in-java-even-if-the-parameterized-constructors-are-p)

Comment: Thank you very much for Mithun response.
I defined an empty constructor and the error has disappeared.
But when you press an item in the listview the application is closed.

Comment: @Natlum You can post a separate question for that with proper and clean code of your latest implementation of your `ListView` `onItemClickListener` , `Adapter`, etc.

Comment: I put another question because I think it will related to the main question.